# RNAseq - Plotting log2foldchange-basemean but has weird data points

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am new to processing RNA seq data and am now practicing to reproduce a published figure related to RNA seq. [This](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jnatprod.7b00734) os the paper and [Fig2A](https://pubs.acs.org/cms/10.1021/acs.jnatprod.7b00734/asset/images/large/np-2017-00734v_0002.jpeg) is what I'm trying to achieve.

In brief, I downloaded the code with recount3 and subset the sample for groups that I want (control vs condition 1, control vs condition 2, etc). Then I performed the following code:

```
dds_4uM_30min <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = ha_4uM_30min_data,
                              colData = ha_4uM_30min_meta,
                              design = ~ type)

dds2_4uM_30min <- DESeq(dds_4uM_30min)

res_4uM_30min <- results(dds2_4uM_30min, tidy=F)
```

(`type` is the column that I made to contain the information of whether it's control or condition 1)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTTB2.png) is the figure I get, which confuses me since it is nowhere near the original figure.

I thought that they might do additional processing of the data, but have no idea what are the common or reasonable ways to do.

Furthermore, there seems to be datapoints that form lines (as can seen in the above figure), which is not seen by in the original figure. I am wondering what causes this kind of distribution and how to adjust for getting rid of it.

Thanks in advance for any opinion or suggestion.

I have been trying to use the function `lfcShrink` but [the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eW4N.png) still has this weird line.

Any suggestions on how to further process RNA seq data?